# How to merge list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, merge, append

I'm extending my original question here: [How to append/merge list of dictionaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61374241/how-to-append-merge-list-of-dictionaries).

I'm trying to merge some data between a single List of dictionaries that has lists inside. Merging would happen based on the "object" and "semver" key if they matched. Also adding to their given "section" if the same value was matched. Given the following data:

```
data = [
        {
         "semver":"1.0.0",
         "sections":[
            {
               "name":"Add",
               "messages":[
                  "add: comment here"
               ]
            }
         ],
         "object":"files.sh"
      },
      {
         "semver":"1.0.0",
         "sections":[
            {
               "name":"Add",
               "messages":[
                  "add: Second comment here"
               ]
            }
         ],
         "object":"files.sh"
      },
      {
         "semver":"1.0.0",
         "sections":[
            {
               "name":"Fix",
               "messages":[
                  "Comment here"
               ]
            }
         ],
         "object":"files.sh"
      },
      {
         "semver":"2.0.0",
         "sections":[
            {
               "name":"Fix",
               "messages":[
                  "2.0.0 Fix Comment here"
               ]
            }
         ],
         "object":"files.sh"
      },
      {
         "semver":"2.0.0",
         "sections":[
            {
               "name":"Add",
               "messages":[
                  "2.0.0 Add Comment here"
               ]
            }
         ],
         "object":"files.sh"
      },
      {
         "semver":"2.0.0",
         "sections":[
            {
               "name":"Add",
               "messages":[
                  "2.0.0 comment for the NewFile"
               ]
            }
         ],
         "object":"NewFile.sh"
      },
]
```

I would like to achieve this as a end result

```
data = [
        {
         "semver":"1.0.0",
         "sections":[
            {
               "name":"Add",
               "messages":[
                  "add: comment here",
                  "add: Second comment here"
               ]
            },
            {
               "name":"Fix",
               "messages":[
                  "Fix: comment here"
               ]
            }
         ],
         "object":"files.sh"
      },
        {
         "semver":"2.0.0",
         "sections":[
            {
               "name":"Add",
               "messages":[
                  "2.0.0 Add comment here",
               ]
            },
            {
               "name":"Fix",
               "messages":[
                  "2.0.0 Fix Comment here"
               ]
            }
         ],
         "object":"files.sh"
      },
      {
         "semver":"2.0.0",
         "sections":[
            {
               "name":"Add",
               "messages":[
                  "2.0.0 comment for the NewFile"
               ]
            }
         ],
         "object":"NewFile.sh"
      },

]
```

Code Block

```
objects = {}  # mapping for object: object_data with sections
sections = defaultdict(list)  # mapping for object: all sections
for d in data:
    print(d["semver"])
    for k, v in list(d.items()):
        if v == d["semver"]:
            try:
                section = d.pop("sections")
                sections[d["object"]].extend(section)
                objects[d["object"]] = d  # populate with object data without sections
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                pass

output = []
for object_name, object_data in objects.items():
    object_data["sections"] = sections[object_name]
    output.append(object_data)
```

So far I am looping through each k,v pair in the `dict`'s but can't wrap my head around matching between the two versions and appending to that specific `dict` in the loop.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to concat the `sections` lists for same combination of `object` and `semver`, right?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 changes that should be done:

1. changing the keys in `objects` and `sections` to be based on combination of `object` and `semver` represented by a tuple.
2. add an auxiliary function to merge the messages in sections

Try this:

```
import json  # just for pretty print, you don't have to use it
from collections import defaultdict


def merge_messages(sections):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for m in sections:
        d[m["name"]].extend(m["messages"])
    return [{"name": k, "messages": v} for k, v in d.items()]


objects = {}  # mapping for data with sections for (object, semver) combinations
sections = defaultdict(list)  # mapping for sections data for (object, semver) combinations
for d in data:
    section = d.pop("sections")
    sections[(d["object"], d["semver"])].extend(section)  # extends the sections for the object
    objects[(d["object"], d["semver"])] = d  # # populate with object data without sections

# merge between sections and objects by object key
output = []
for comb, object_data in objects.items():
    object_data["sections"] = merge_messages(sections[comb])
    output.append(object_data)
print(json.dumps(output, indent=4))  # just for pretty print
```

Comment: I thought the OP wants to combine the sections if the server and object are the same and combine the messages if the name is the same.

Comment: Thanks Gabip, as @Bobby Ocean did mention. I am as well trying to  combine the messages if the original name is the same. I guess this can be changed from (extend) in the code?

Comment: @Boojs I've updated my solution, please check it out